# Enum and unsigned long bitfields

Tags: c, struct, enums, bit-fields

If I have the following struct with an enum and unsigned long, how is the padding accomplished? I believe the compiler wont do anything with `var1` and `var2` since it is 32 bits and filled.

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long var1 : 8;
    unsigned long var2 : 24;
    my_enum var3       : 2;
    my_enum var4       : 2;
} my_struct;
```

Would there be a padding for both `var3` and `var4`? such as 30 bits of padding to `var3` and 30 bits to `var4`, or 28 bits. I'm just trying to understand how bitfields work across different data types and implementation types.

Comment: C or C++, choice only one language because your question is too broad with two languages.

Comment: I'm using g++ compiler if it helps. Its hard to say because the large project I have been working on is both c and c++. The file is a .c file so I would say C

Comment: The choose is up to you, this enum is used in a cpp file too ? or only used in c file only ? The problem is that your question can generate two different answer. For example, use a `long` integer for a bit field is invalid in C but not in C++.

Comment: The struct is defined in the .h file but is being used in a .c file and compiled by g++.

Comment: Start by printing `sizeof(my_struct)`. Then you know how much padding that has been used.

Comment: Look [here under 6. Bifields](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/), it is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.
Types used in a bitfield:**

I would only use `signed int` or `unsigned int` in your stucture as bitfield type. According to the [C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (6.7.2.1 #4):

> A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of
>   **_Bool**, **signed int**, **unsigned int**, or some other implementation-defined type.

Sure an `unsigned long` and `enum type` are implementation-defined types, but if you use them the behaviour is not portable. You can see it in 2 different GCC versions:

According to the manual for [gcc 4.8.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.4/gcc/Structures-unions-enumerations-and-bit-fields-implementation.html):

> - Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned int (C99 6.7.2.1).
>
> No other types are permitted in strictly conforming mode.

According to the manual for [gcc-5.2.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/gcc.pdf):

> - Allowable bit-field types other than _Bool, signed int, and unsigned int (C99 and C11 6.7.2.1).
>
> Other integer types, such as long int, and enumerated types are permitted even in strictly conforming mode.

**2.
Padding:**

Bitfields are working in word and byte level and cannot cross word boundaries. C99 guarentees that bitfields will be packed as tightly as possible, provided they don’t cross storage unit boundaries (6.7.2.1 #10).

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-
>   field.  If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
>   structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit.  If insufficient space remains,
>   whether  a  bit-field  that  does  not  fit  is  put  into  the  next  unit  or  overlaps  adjacent  units  is
>   implementation-defined.  The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
>   low-order  or  low-order  to  high-order)  is  implementation-defined.  The  alignment  of  the
>   addressable storage unit is unspecified.

If you you want to pad the exisiting bit fields in a unit up the the next unit you can do it with a length zero bitfield as said in the standard (6.7.2.1 #11):

> As  a  special  case,  a  bit-field  structure  member  with  a  width  of  0
>   indicates  that  no  further  bit-field  is  to  be  packed  into  the  unit  in  which  the  previous  bit-
>   field, if any, was placed.

Further it says something about the end in [C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (6.7.2.1 #15):

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

---

**What that means for your struct:**

You `var1` and `var2` will be stored together in 4 byte (32 bit) of memory without any gaps. Because bitfields can operate at byte level your `var3` and `var4` can also be stored together representing one byte. But the order of them is implementaion defined.
If you put a zero length bit field in between of them the `var4` would start at the next aligned unit. The end of your structure will may be padded up to 32 bit or 64 bit.

---

**Real code example with your struct:**

Because you can't take addresses of bitfields it is not so easy to analyse the bahaviour of bitfields, here is a little piece of code that I wrote to analyse it with a little workaround anyway.

I set the values inside the structure with a bit pattern that is easy to recognize and print out every bit of the whole structure (total size with `sizeof()`). You can see the [result on ideone](https://ideone.com/OxkAVi), or below. Note that the used system uses little-endian format per structure variable, therefore the bytes are swapped in contrast to the humand readable form (big-endian format). Also the `var3` and `var4` are in a different order as the standard says that it is implementation defined.

**Output:**

```
sizeof(my_struct)     = 8
sizeof(my_struct_var) = 8
Byte 0:  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
Byte 1:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
Byte 2:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Byte 3:  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Byte 4:  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
Byte 5:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Byte 6:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Byte 7:  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Your structure uses effectively the byte 0 to 3 and a half of byte 4. Because I compiled on a 64 bit machine and ideone too, the half byte 4 is padded up to byte 7. Also I recommend reading this [guideline about structure padding and bitfields](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/).

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#if CHAR_BIT != 8
#error "unsupported char size"
#endif

typedef enum { ONE, TWO, THREE } my_enum;

typedef struct
{
   unsigned long var1 : 8;
   unsigned long var2 : 24;
   my_enum       var3 : 2;
   my_enum       var4 : 2;
} my_struct;

int main(void)
{
   int idx;
   int bitIdx;
   my_struct my_struct_var;

   memset (&my_struct_var,
           0,
           sizeof(my_struct_var));

   printf("sizeof(my_struct)     = %lu\n", sizeof(my_struct));
   printf("sizeof(my_struct_var) = %lu\n", sizeof(my_struct_var));

   my_struct_var.var1 = 0x81;     /* 1000 0001                     */
   my_struct_var.var2 = 0x800001; /* 1000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 */
   my_struct_var.var3 = 0b10;     /* 10                            */
   my_struct_var.var4 = 0b11;     /* 11                            */

   for (idx = 0; idx < sizeof(my_struct_var); ++idx)
   {
      char * curByte = &my_struct_var;
      curByte += idx;
      printf("\nByte %d:  ", idx);
      for (bitIdx = 0; bitIdx < CHAR_BIT; ++bitIdx)
      {
         printf("%c ", ((*curByte & (1 << ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - bitIdx))) >> ((CHAR_BIT - 1) - bitIdx)) + '0');
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This visualization is perfect. Thanks

Comment: @user3128077 This answer may be valid for the system and compiler where it was constructed. But there's nothing in the C (or C++ I think) standard that says the results will be the same with others.

Comment: @Gene: Yes thank you, I added what the C99 standard is saying about bitfields. If the OP want's to know the bahviour of different platforms/compiler he could use the C code in this answer.